# Irritating Text Wrapping with GDI & Direct3D

Tags: c++, gdi, direct3d, word-wrap

If I use Direct3D's DrawText, which behaves like the GDI counterpart, and I enable the `DT_WORDBREAK` formatting flag, it'll cut the text on apostrophes whenever the situation arises, which leaves many titles and text displays looking like a mess. For instance, it will appear as:

> The Horseman'
>   s Head

When it should say:

> The
>   Horseman's
>   Head

It seems unlikely considering the restrictive nature of the font handling functions, but is there any way of specifying it so that it only cuts text on white-space or when there's absolutely nothing that can be done?

Comment: From the D3DX utility library (ID3DXFont::DrawText)? I don't believe core D3D has a DrawText function. Direct2D does though, and D2D's DrawText doesn't appear to have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap manually with the help of the [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

I've run in to this before, and the only solution is to write your own word wrapper, using DT_CALCRECT to measure the width of a given string.  It's annoying and it does suck, but I've never seen an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so (i may be wrong). But you can set a "virtual" limit on a Width. Calculate line length (char_count*font_width) and make the jumps yourself. You can even add special char "\n", to insert your own jumps...

Comment: Using `char_count * font_width` isn't a very good solution considering the font has varying character sizes.

Comment: @Jengerer: You're absolutely right, better to use something like GetTextExtentPoint32

Comment: @codebolt: That's actually a very helpful function for solving the problem. If you could throw that suggestion into a separate answer, I'll accept that as it seems to be the most efficient solution. Thanks!